# settear los valores de un checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, datatable

1 funcionamiento: Mediante un select->option cargo información a un div el cual contendrá un form y dentro de dicho form una tabla con un checkbox general que controla si se tienen que marcar todos los checkboxes o no de la tabla y despues tiene un checkbox por cara row junto con info.

2 El problema: a la hora de editar  relleno correctamente el select->option pero no consigo que se marquen los checkboxes que corresponden de hecho no consigo que se marque ningun checkbox.

He quitado ciertas funciones que no pintaban mucho como el ajax que enviaba los datos hacia el servidor

`vista Blade`

```
<div class="container col">
    <div class="card subCabeceraModal">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <select class="form-control" id="clienteFusion">
                    <option value="">Selecciona un Cliente</option>
                    @foreach ($clientes as  $var)
                        <option value="{{ $var->idCliente }}">{{ Str::length($var->cliente) >30?  Str::substr($var->cliente, 0, 30).'....':$var->cliente}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" id="engancheOfertas">
                <div id="tablaOfertas" style="height: 700px">
                @if($ventas!='')
                <div class="table-responsive" style="height: 500px">
                    <form id="fusionOfertasForm" name="fusionOfertasForm">
                        @csrf
                        <table class="table tablaPersonalizada table-bordered table-striped mb-0" style="overflow-y:auto;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="col-1 cabeceraTabla">
                                        <input  type="checkbox" id="selectAllFusionOferta" name="selectAllFusionOferta">
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="col-1 cabeceraTabla">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="col-2 cabeceraTabla">FECHA</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="col-2 cabeceraTabla">TIPO</th>
                                <th scope="col"class="col-7 cabeceraTabla">OBSERVACIONES</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($ventas  as $venta)
                                        <tr id="{{$venta->oferta->idOferta}}">
                                            <td>
                                                <input  type="checkbox" class="selectFusionOferta" value="{{ $venta->oferta}}" name="selectFusionOferta[]">
                                            </td>
                                            <th scope="row">{{$venta->oferta->idOferta}} </th>
                                            <td>   {{ date("j-n-Y", strtotime($venta->oferta->fechaEnvioOfertaInicial))}} </td>
                                            <td>{{$venta->tipo}}</td>
                                            <td> {{$venta->oferta->observaciones}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="col mt-3">
                            <button id="fusionOfertasFormBoton" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Fusión</button>
                        </div>
                 

                    </form>
                </div>
                  @endif
       
<script>
    $(function(){
        let validacion=0;
        $('#clienteFusion').on('change', function(){
            addInfoTabla($('#clienteFusion').val());
        });
        //selectores
        $('#engancheOfertas').on('change', '#selectAllFusionOferta',function(){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
            $('#fusionOfertasFormBoton').attr('disabled', false);
        })
        function editar(){
            let editarCliente_id= <?php echo isset($editarCliente_id)?$editarCliente_id:0; ?> ;
            let editarOfertas_id=  <?php echo  isset($editarOfertas_id)?json_encode($editarOfertas_id):0; ?>;
            let ruta= "{{ $ruta ?? '' }}";
            if (editarCliente_id!=0 && editarOfertas_id!=0 && ruta!='') {
               console.log(editarOfertas_id);

                //Cargo la informacion en los respectivos sitios
                    //select
                    $('#clienteFusion').val(editarCliente_id);
                    addInfoTabla($('#clienteFusion').val());
            }
        }
        editar();
        function addInfoTabla(cliente){
            $.get('/ofertas-crear-grupos',{cliente: cliente } , function(respuesta){
                        $("#tablaOfertas").html( $(respuesta).find(' #tablaOfertas'));
                        validacion= $("#fusionOfertasForm").validate({debug: true,rules:{"selectFusionOferta[]":{required:true}}});
                    });
        }





    });
</script>
```

Comment: los `select` se marcan por defecto con el atributo `selected` en el `option` y los `checkbox` con el atributo `checked`; en que momento haces eso??? si no lo haces tienes que hacerlo, esa parte no la logro ver en tu codigo...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 En la función editar mediante jquery le paso el valor y relleno el div con el form y la tabla

Comment: ahora quede mas perdido... si esto lo estas haciendo en php y la consulta o tabla viene desde php... no deberia de vernir de php esos checkbox marcados?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 a que te refieres con márcalos mediante php?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507  Si te refieres algo como esto  <input  type="checkbox" class="selectFusionOferta" value="{{ $venta->oferta}}"
                                                name="selectFusionOferta[]" {{  ($venta->oferta->idOferta == 12 ? ' checked' : '') }} >   lo he pensado pero no me termina de funcionar segun blade la variable que contiene las ids no existe

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 lo curioso es que depues en el js la llamo y funciona me coge el array con las ids

Comment: Esta mal planteado: si la tabla es rellenada por ajax si tendria sentido que mediante ajax determines que checkbox debe ir marcado (checked)... si la tabla viene armada desde php no tiene sentido esto ultimo... y deberias hacer funcionar eso que dices que no funciona, ese seria realmente la via y el problema a resolver... y no se usa `idOferta` estoy casi seguro que seria algo como `getIdOferta` asumiendo que debe tener getter y setter...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Buenas de nuevo, perdona que haya tardado tanto en contestar, vamos por partes, esto lo estoy desarrollando en Laravel entonces desde el controlador mando un parametro que sellama venta que contiene el modelo entero de la venta. Segundo se hace una llamada ajax para cargar la tabla cuando cambia el select o cuando estas editando se le inyecta esa info yo se que mi codigo es un poco caotico, no es que este mal planteado que pueda ser yo tampoco soy un experto de primer nivel.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Encontré el fallo por alguna razón que desconozco hace una llamada al controlador de editar donde se le pasan los parámetros y hace otra llamada al controlador de crear donde no se le pasan estos parámetros estoy viendo si es que he repetido nombres o algo así en los botones

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ya lo tengo resuelto te acuerdas que al principio me decías que por qué no lo hacía poniendo los valores desde Laravel en lugar de hacerlo de la manera que lo estaba haciendo, pues tenías razón lo he conseguido hacer mediante el controlador de Laravel, resulta que el True fallo era que había una variable que controla las filas que se envía y la estaba llamando con otro nombre, por lo cual siempre me enviaba las filas vacías hasta que hacia la llamada ajax y se llenaban pero esa parte ya la he quitado, Gracias por la ayuda !!

Comment: no hay que ser experto de primer nivel para lo que te estoy diciendo... estas ocupado mas de 1 request al servidor para cargar dicha informacion... busca como cargar por ajax elemento dentro de tu tabla... y en el caso de checkbox mostrarlos marcados... debe haber algo en el foro del sitio del plugin...

Comment: te lo digo con experiencia, de lo contrario no pudiera yo hacer esto: https://i.imgur.com/1LS1BCO.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas intentando implementar es incorrecto; según los comentarios, como te decía si estás trabajando con laravel y quieres desplegar elementos dentro de la tabla debes usar los recursos para generar los `checkbox` desde el `php`, y no mediante ajax o mediante un script javascript que seleccione por el usuario en la consulta, cuando estos elementos ya pueden venir con el atributo `checked`.

Lo interesante en este aspecto es que estas realizando 2 o 3 request innecesarios cuando blade te provee de las herramientas que necesitas para obtener el mismo resultado que esperas.

Tienes que validad que no tengas errores de sintaxis y que cada variable paso a paso tenga lo que esperas en los posibles escenarios.

Comment: pues tienes razón tenía cosas mal y aparte está el punto de la tabla que es como señalas. pero ya lo tengo arreglado